# In what order does Apache evaluate `RedirectRule` when provided by virtual host, directory context and .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have several `RewriteRule` inside `<VirtualHost>`, inside the `<Directory>` directive which belongs to the web root of said `<VirtualHost>` and inside `.htaccess` of that directory.

*Question:* In what order does Apache 2.4 evaluate those `RewriteRules`?

I tried to read [Apache Docs - How the sections are merged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging), but I am lost and I am not sure if the rules given in that section apply to `RewriteRule`.

My simplified Apache config looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.my-domain.tld
  ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.tld
  DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^/something" "/somewhat"
  RewriteRule "^/something-else" "/foo"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
  Require all granted
  AllowOverride All
  Options FollowSymLinks

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^something" "nothing"
  RewriteRule "^something-else" "bar"

  DirectoryIndex index.html
</Directory>
```

and the `.htaccess`

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "^foo" "bar"
  RewriteRule "^nothing" "something"
```

In particular, the following aspects confuses me:

- `.htaccess` is said to *overwrite* `<Directory>`, does this mean that any `RewriteRule` inside `<Directory>` is completely ignored as if it was not there at all as soon as there is a single `RewriteRule` inside `.htaccess`?
- Sections inside `<VirtualHost>` are said to be evaluated *after*  any other section in order to allow *overwriting*. IMHO, this statement does not make sense in case of `RewriteRule` (or is at least confusing), because an earlier rewrite rule "wins".

Comment: As a general rule - do not use `.htacess` when you have full admin rights and access to Apache main server configuration and set [`AllowOverride None`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#allowoverride). Support for `.htaccess` is intended for shared hosting where web masters don't have access to the main server config. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html#when - When you do need  `.htaccess` then simply put all your configuration in `.htaccess` files and don't use both. Inconsistency will lead to unnecessary complexity as you're already experiencing.

Comment: The technical details are in the manual here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html and not for the faint of heart.

Comment: I know that using the configuration file is beneficial, not at last because it is faster as the configuration file is only read and cached once, while `.htaccess` is read on every request. But while I myself have access to the Apache config as I am the server admin, I provide web space to other uses and they have to use `.htaccess`. So I try to figure out how everything plays together.

Comment: just to clarify @user2690527 .htaccess is read "several times" for every request, not just once